# android layout doesn't apprea

Tags: android, android-layout

i have two layouts vertically , first one has edittext and button, second one has two listvies ,
the first one doesn't appear, and i got an exception when running the application

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etRestaurantSearchName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Enter name"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textSize="15dip" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bRestaurantSearchButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Search" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvRestaurants"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:fillViewport="true" >
        </ListView>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvAlphabets"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="@drawable/foods_alphabets_bg"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

i ma sure it is something about hiegh , width or weight,

Comment: Please provide the logcat of your crash.

Comment: please use LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout

Comment: when i remove the listviews it works well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used RelativeLayout as the parent layout for the inner two layouts. Therefore the second inner Linear Layout overlaps the first one , thus first one cant be seen. Make use of linear layout as parent layout

Comment: i will accept your asnwer, please tell me when to use linear and when relative

Comment: You can use either of them. If the layout is very simple go for  linear layout. Sometimes you may need one view on top 2 below it den 1 below and .. lot complicated . Then instead of creating a big nesting of linear layouts yu can use relative layout

Comment: @FernadoMargin The lesser the hierarchical size of the layout faster will be the parsing of the xml. So in most cases relative layouts mi8 turn out to be a better choice. In case you have to use the attribute gravity then you might have to use linear layouts

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Correction :
android:layout_below="@+id/Layout1" for layout two.
and some weight related changes.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/Layout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etRestaurantSearchName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Enter name"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textSize="15dip" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bRestaurantSearchButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Search" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Layout1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvRestaurants"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
        android:fillViewport="true" >
    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvAlphabets"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_bg_pressed"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```